# Bash: Running one command after another using string variable

Tags: linux, bash

I understand that running one command after another is done in bash using the following command

```
command1 && command2
```

or

```
command1; command2
```

or even

```
command1 & command2
```

I also understand that a command stored in a bash variable can be run by simply firing the variable as:

```
TestCommand="ls"
$TestCommand
```

Doing the above will list all the files in the directory and I have tested that it does.

But doing the same with multiple commands generates an error. Sample below:

```
TestCommand="ls && ls -l"
$TestCommand
ls: cannot access &&: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
```

My question is why is this happening and is there any workaround?

And before you bash me for doing something so stupid. The preceding is just to present the problem. I have a list of files in my directory and I am using sed to convert the list into a single executable string. Storing that string in a bash variable, I am trying to run it but failing.

Comment: The dangerous way is to `eval` that string. You want to execute all the files in a directory? Do you want to abort if one fails? You could go for a `for loop`.

Comment: When you want to execute custom commands by giving them a name *write a function* e.g. `myfunction() { include your commands here }`. You can then call `myfunction` any time after it is declared in your code. Also recognize that `command1 && command2` or `command1 || command2` are called *compound commands*. Including a `';'` following a command is simply and `end-of-line`. I don't believe your bitwise `&` of commands is doing what you think it is.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I just wanted to know why this is not working. And I observed the behaviour of using `';'` is same as that of `'&&'` and so is `'&'`. I couldn't spot the difference. Would you know the difference?

Comment: The `';'` is not the same as `&&`. The `';'` is just an `end-of-line` it has no bearing on whether there was a successful completion of the command before it. `&&` is a compound command operator that effectively says *execute `command2` if, and only if there is a successful completion of `command1` in `command1 && command2`*. Try it `ls foo; printf "after foo\n"` and then `ls foo && printf "after foo\n"` Now try `ls /home || printf "after foo\n"` (`||` meaning if `command1` *fails*, then `command2`. `command1 & command2` is nothing but a bitwise and of the returns of 1 & 2. Hope this helped.

Comment: Note, I stand corrected an `'&'` separator or terminator shall cause asynchronous execution of the preceding list of *compound commands*. (e.g. it causes the preceding command to be executed in the background, rather than synchronously with the command that follows. Note. *compound command* is also known as an *asynchronous* list or *and-or* list in POSIX shell. (see e.g. [**Asynchronous Lists**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02) ) I wasn't thinking about it as a connector, but it is, just strange to think of it that way -- after 20 years

Answer (score 1):

When you put two command in a single string variable, it is executed as single command. so when you are using **"$TestCommand"** to execute two **"ls"** commands, it is executing only one(first) **"ls"** command. it considers **&&** and **ls**(second) as argument of first **ls** command.

As your current working directory is not having any files named && and ls it is returning error :

```
    ls: cannot access &&: No such file or directory
    ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
```

So, basically your commands behaves like this

```
    ls file1 file2 -l
```

and it will give you output like this if file1 and file2 exists:

```
    HuntM@~/scripts$ ls file1 file2 -l
    -rw-r--r-- 1 girishp staff 0 Dec  8 12:44 file1
    -rw-r--r-- 1 girishp staff 0 Dec  8 12:44 file2
```

Now your solution:

You can create function OR one more script to execute 2 commands as below:

caller.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    myLs=`./myls.sh`
    echo "$myLs"
```

myls.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ls && ls -l
```